# Printing certain number of rows using awk. AND skipping certain rows

Tags: parsing, unix, awk

I have a simple question, which is almost too simple to find on this forum or on awk learning sites.

I have some awk code that matches a line beginning with a number, and prints the 6th column of that line:

```
/^[1-9]/ {   
print $6 
}
```

How do I tell it to print only the first 50 rows of the column from the match?

---

### ADDITIONAL QUESTION

I tried used my own version of the answers below and I got it to print 50 lines. However, now I am trying to choose which 50 lines I print. I do this by skipping a line that starts with a number and contains the word 'residue'. Then I skip 5 lines that start with a number and contain a 'w'. This method is working as if I am only skipping the line with residue and prints from the first line starting with a number after that. Do you know why my 'w's are not being considered.

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f

BEGIN {
    line  = 0;
    skipW = 0;
}


# Ignore all lines beginning with a number until I find one I'm interested in.
/^[0-9]+ residue/ { next }

# Ignore the first five lines beginning with a number followed by a 'w'.
/^[0-9]+ w/ { 
    skipW += 1;
    if (skipW <= 5) next
}

# For all other lines beginning with a number, perform the following.  If we are
# "printing", increment the line count.  When we've printed 50 lines turn off
# printing from that point on.
/^[0-9]+/ { 
    ++line
    if ((line > 0) && (line <= 50)) print $6
}
```

Comment: Your program seems correct. It will be helpful to show an example of your data where it fails.

Comment: You say 'skipping lines that start with a number and contain the word _residue_', but the code code doesn't do that; it skips lines that start with a number followed immediately by the word _residue_.  You'd need something like `/^[0-9]+ .*residue/` to do what you say you want.  Similarly with lines that 'start with a number and contain a _w_'.

Comment: can you think of a way to match multi-line patterns. Like if there is a pattern 4 lines in a row where they start with a number and then have a letter such as 1 q 2 r 3 i 4 l

Comment: You can do some sort of messing around with an array of the $0 records, and keep a tab on which one contains the first line and the fourth line and see what goes on.  Fiddly, messy, but probably OK.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12718429/matching-regex-of-multiple-lines-in-awk-operator

Comment: I clarified my problem in that question, if you are interested.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
awk '/^[1-9]/ { if (num_printed++ < 50) print $6 }'
```

This increments `num_printed` each time a match is found and prints out the first 50 such lines, regardless of where the lines are in the files in the input.

This reads through all the input.  If an early exit is OK, then you can use:

```
awk '/^[1-9]/ { print $6; if (++num_printed == 50) exit }'
```

Note the switch from post-increment to pre-increment.

Answer (score 3):

Use a match counter as part of your condition:

```
/^[1-9]/ && matched < 50 {
    print $6
    matched++
}
```

You can use a *shortcut* method also:

```
/^[1-9]/ { print $6; matched++ }
matched == 50 { exit }
```

But this may not always work on a pipline, if the *producer* command does not handle `SIGPIPE` gracefully.

Comment: This only looks for matches in the first 50 lines of input, rather than printing out the first 50 matching lines.

Comment: I don't have to initialize matched to 0 in a BEGIN statement?

Comment: No; variables are automagically initialized to zero when they are first used.