# Matching regex of multiple lines in AWK. && operator?

Tags: python, regex, parsing, awk

I am not sure if the && operator works in regular expressions. What I am trying to do is match a line such that it starts with a number and has the letter 'a' AND the next line starts with a number and has the letter 'b' AND the next line... letter 'c'. This abc sequence will be used as a unique identifier to start reading the file.

Here is what I am sort of going for in awk.

```
/(^[0-9]+ .*a)&&\n(^[0-9]+ .*b)&&\n(^[0-9]+ .*c) {
print $0
}
```

Just one of these regex works like (^[0-9]+ .*a), but I am not sure how to string them together with AND THE NEXT LINE IS THIS.

My file would be like:

```
JUNK UP HERE NOT STARTING WITH NUMBER
1     a           0.110     0.069          
2     a           0.062     0.088          
3     a           0.062     0.121          
4     b           0.062     0.121          
5     c           0.032     0.100         
6     d           0.032     0.100          
7     e           0.032     0.100
```

And what I want is:

```
3     a           0.062     0.121          
4     b           0.062     0.121          
5     c           0.032     0.100         
6     d           0.032     0.100          
7     e           0.032     0.100
```

Comment: For your case, because your "clauses" (the three conditions you want to AND together) don't overlap, you don't really need any operator at all, just "eat up" the rest of the line the way @m.buettner suggests. In cases where your conditions _do_ overlap, like if you wanted to check that a line contained a symbol AND a number (but you don't know the order), then you would use what are called "lookahead assertions" to achieve this kind of matching.

Comment: Only lookahead assertion I know is the next() function in python. I attempted it in an answer below.

Comment: I'm not familiar with Python but I was talking about the lookahead and lookbehind constructs, which I do know Python supports: http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Update based on clarification.]

One high order bit is that Awk is a line-oriented language, so you won't actually be able to do a normal pattern match to span lines. The usual way to do something like this is to match each line separately, and have a later clause / statement figure out if all the right pieces have been matched.

What I'm doing here is looking for an `a` in the second field on one line, a `b` in the second field on another line, and a `c` in the second field on a third line. In the first two cases, I stash away the contents of the line as well as what line number it occurred on. When the third line is matched and we haven't yet found the whole sequence, I go back and check to see if the other two lines are present and with acceptable line numbers. If all's good, I print out the buffered previous lines and set a flag indicating that everything else should print.

Here's the script:

```
$2 == "a" { a = $0; aLine = NR; }
$2 == "b" { b = $0; bLine = NR; }
$2 == "c" && !keepPrinting {
    if ((bLine == (NR - 1)) && (aLine == (NR - 2))) {
        print a;
        print b;
        keepPrinting = 1;
    }
}
keepPrinting { print; }
```

And here's a file I tested it with:

```
JUNK UP HERE NOT STARTING WITH NUMBER
1     a           0.110     0.069
2     a           0.062     0.088
3     a           0.062     0.121
4     b           0.062     0.121
5     c           0.032     0.100
6     d           0.032     0.100
7     e           0.032     0.100
8     a           0.099     0.121
9     b           0.098     0.121
10    c           0.097     0.100
11    x           0.000     0.200
```

Here's what I get when I run it:

```
$ awk -f blort.awk blort.txt
3     a           0.062     0.121
4     b           0.062     0.121
5     c           0.032     0.100
6     d           0.032     0.100
7     e           0.032     0.100
8     a           0.099     0.121
9     b           0.098     0.121
10    c           0.097     0.100
11    x           0.000     0.200
```

Comment: That is similar to what I want. I should have mentioned that abc will be a unique sequence in my file. I'll be using it as a starting point to read. So the output I would like from your test file is the lines with a,b,c,d,e,a,b,c,x

Comment: I updated my answer based on your comments. The state machine solution you posted is interesting from an academic perspective, but perhaps something like this one is more practical?

Comment: Thanks danfuzz. And easier for me to explain the script to my boss than the state machine. All I did was add {if ((keepPrinting > 0) && (++keepPrinting <= 50)) print $0} to get the number of lines I want after matching.

Answer (score 1):

No it doesn't work. You could try something like this:

```
/(^[0-9]+.*a[^\n]*)\n([0-9]+.*b[^\n]*)\n([0-9]+.*c[^\n]*)/
```

And repeat that for as many letters as you need.

The `[^\n]*` will match as much non-linebreak characters in a row as possible (so up to the linebreak).

Comment: No that did not. Thanks for telling me that though

Comment: just for the fun of it, try replacing `[^\n]` with a `.` in all three instances

Comment: no I meant delete the `[^\n]` and just use `.` ... if that doesn't do it, unfortunately, I'm out of ideas for today

Comment: How do you get the multiple newlines into `$0`?  By default, `awk` reads a single line at a time, so `$0` never contains the newlines you're looking for.

Comment: Ah okay. I'm not familiar with `awk`, so I just assumed the regex he wants would work on his given input as one string.

Answer (score 0):

A friend wrote this awk program for me. It is a state machine. And it works.

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f

BEGIN {
    # We start out in the "idle" state.
    state = "idle"
}

/^[0-9]+[[:space:]]+q/ {
    # Everytime we encounter a "# q" we either print it or go to the
    # "q_found" state.
    if (state != "printing") {
        state = "q_found"
        line_q = $0
    }
}

/^[0-9]+[[:space:]]+r/ {
    # If we are in the q_found state and "# r" immediate follows,
    # advance to the r_found state.  Else, return to "idle" and 
    # wait for the "# q" to start us off.
    if (state == "q_found") {
        state = "r_found"
        line_r = $0
    } else if (state != "printing") {
        state = "idle"
    }
}

/^[0-9]+[[:space:]]+l/ {
    # If we are in the r_found state and "# l" immediate follows,
    # advance to the l_found state.  Else, return to "idle" and 
    # wait for the "# q" to start us off.
    if (state == "r_found") {
        state = "l_found"
        line_l = $0
    } else if (state != "printing") {
        state = "idle"
    }
}

/^[0-9]+[[:space:]]+i/ {
    # If we are in the l_found state and "# i" immediate follows,
    # we're ready to start printing.  First, display the lines we
    # squirrelled away then move to the "printing" state.  Else,
    # go to "idle" and wait for the "# q" to start us off.
    if (state == "l_found") {
        state = "printing"
        print line_q
        print line_r
        print line_l
        line = 0
    } else if (state != "printing") {
        state = "idle"
    }
}

/^[0-9]+[[:space:]]+/ {
    # If in state "printing", print 50 lines then stop printing
    if (state == "printing") {
        if (++line < 48) print
    }
}
```