# Insert comment // when conditions do not match

Tags: awk, sed

How to get the desired output?
For a text file, when one of these conditions are met:

```
- the first field of a line has the string "type" or "const" (all lowercase)
- the line has "(" and ")" and do not have the string "ch" followed by a number (e.g. "ch6")
- a multiline which start with "{" somewhere of a line and end with "}" as the first character of a line
- the line start with comment "//"
- empty lines or lines of all white space
- a line has "{" and "}"
```

then print (as usual),
else insert comment "//" in the beginning of line and print

e.g.
input:

```
TypeScript ch6 (2/3) Advanced Function Types
 Types TypeScript  
  Totality TSC Flag: noImplicitReturns Advanced Object Types
   The keyof operator TSC Flag: keyofStringsOnly The Record Type Mapped Types Built-in mapped types 
type Weekday = 'Mon' | 'Tue' | 'Wed'|'Thu'|'Fri'

type Day = Weekday | 'Sat' | 'Sun'
// Error: Function lacks ending return statement and return type does not include 'undefined'.
function getNextDay(w: Weekday): Day {
  switch(w) {
    case 'Mon': return 'Tue'
  }
}
{  }
{
}
{
  {
    test
  }
}
const i = 1
 TSC Flag: noImplicitReturns tsconfig"noImplicitReturns": true // Error: Not all code paths return a value.
function isBig(n: number) {
  if (n >= 100) {
    return true
  }
}
 Advanced Object Types Type Operators for Object Types 
 Companion Object Pattern
type APIResponse = {
  user: {
    userId: string,
    friendList: {
      count: number,
      friends: {
        firstName: string,
        lastName: string
      }[]
    }
  }
}
function getAPIResponse(): Promise<APIResponse> {
  // ...
}
const response = await getAPIResponse()
renderFriendList(response.user.friendList)
 friendListtypehint any FriendList
```

output:

```
//TypeScript ch6 (2/3) Advanced Function Types
// Types TypeScript  
//  Totality TSC Flag: noImplicitReturns Advanced Object Types
//   The keyof operator TSC Flag: keyofStringsOnly The Record Type Mapped Types Built-in mapped types 
type Weekday = 'Mon' | 'Tue' | 'Wed'|'Thu'|'Fri'

type Day = Weekday | 'Sat' | 'Sun'
// Error: Function lacks ending return statement and return type does not include 'undefined'.
function getNextDay(w: Weekday): Day {
  switch(w) {
    case 'Mon': return 'Tue'
  }
}
{  }
{
}
{
  {
    test
  }
}
const i = 1
// TSC Flag: noImplicitReturns tsconfig"noImplicitReturns": true // Error: Not all code paths return a value.
function isBig(n: number) {
  if (n >= 100) {
    return true
  }
}
// Advanced Object Types Type Operators for Object Types 
// Companion Object Pattern
type APIResponse = {
  user: {
    userId: string,
    friendList: {
      count: number,
      friends: {
        firstName: string,
        lastName: string
      }[]
    }
  }
}
function getAPIResponse(): Promise<APIResponse> {
  // ...
}
const response = await getAPIResponse()
renderFriendList(response.user.friendList)
// friendListtypehint any FriendList
```

I tried this script, which did not handle properly 'a multiline which start with "{" somewhere of a line and end with "}" as the first character of a line':

```
awk '{
  if ($1 ~ /type/ || $1 ~ /const/ || $0 ~ /\(.*)/ || $0 ~ /{.*}/ || $0 ~ /\/\//)
    print $0;
  else
    if ($0 !~ /}/)
      print "//", $0;
    else 
      print $0;
}' input
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using any awk:

```
$ cat tst.awk
{
    comment = 0
    if ( inBlock ) {
        if ( /^}/ ) {
            inBlock = 0
        }
    }
    else if ( /\{$/ ) {
        inBlock = 1
    }
    else if ( NF && !(                           \
                ( $1 ~ /^(type|const|\/\/)/ ) || \
                ( /\(.*)/ && !/ch[0-9]/ ) ||     \
                ( /\{.*}/ )                      \
            ) ) {
        comment = 1
    }
}
comment {
    $0 = "//" $0
}
{ print }
```

```
$ awk -f tst.awk file
//TypeScript ch6 (2/3) Advanced Function Types
// Types TypeScript
//  Totality TSC Flag: noImplicitReturns Advanced Object Types
//   The keyof operator TSC Flag: keyofStringsOnly The Record Type Mapped Types Built-in mapped types
type Weekday = 'Mon' | 'Tue' | 'Wed'|'Thu'|'Fri'

type Day = Weekday | 'Sat' | 'Sun'
// Error: Function lacks ending return statement and return type does not include 'undefined'.
function getNextDay(w: Weekday): Day {
  switch(w) {
    case 'Mon': return 'Tue'
  }
}
{  }
{
}
{
  {
    test
  }
}
const i = 1
// TSC Flag: noImplicitReturns tsconfig"noImplicitReturns": true // Error: Not all code paths return a value.
function isBig(n: number) {
  if (n >= 100) {
    return true
  }
}
// Advanced Object Types Type Operators for Object Types
// Companion Object Pattern
type APIResponse = {
  user: {
    userId: string,
    friendList: {
      count: number,
      friends: {
        firstName: string,
        lastName: string
      }[]
    }
  }
}
function getAPIResponse(): Promise<APIResponse> {
  // ...
}
const response = await getAPIResponse()
renderFriendList(response.user.friendList)
// friendListtypehint any FriendList
```

Comment: @ Ed Morton and Daweo,
Thank you for your help and scripts :).
I am sorry. My requirements had flaw.
I clarify the requirements to my "do not comment" list.

Comment: @albertkao9 I just updated my answer, it now implements all of your latest requirements end outputs exactly the expected output from your question.

Comment: @ Ed Morton
Thank you very much!!!
Excellent!!!
I learned a lot.
I think your awk script used state machine.
https://blog.ngzhian.com/awk.html described this:
The general rule is then: all the state-changing statements should come first, and the effectful (print or summations), should be at the end.

Comment: @albertkao9 You're welcome. I guess you could consider the inBlock variable as holding state but it;s not really what I'd think of as a state machine.

Comment: @ Ed Morton
What do you think of as an awk state machine?

Comment: Any state machine has a state variable that holds the state. In my code I just have a flag variable with some if-elses. If my code had something like `state="enteringBlock"`, `state="inBlock"`, `state="leavingBlock"`, and `state="outsideBlock"` and did things in the main body of the script instead of in `if-else`s THEN I'd say it's a state machine.

Comment: I've no idea what the author of that link you provided meant by "The general rule is then: all the state-changing statements should come first, and the effectful (print or summations), should be at the end." by the way. As a bit of background/context - unrelated to awk I taught and consulted on behavioral modeling using state machines for about 10 years, have patents on it, articles published in journals about it, and had a paper about it presented at OOPSLA.

Comment: idk how good a script it is but some googling shows someone posted a state machine written in awk at https://stackoverflow.com/a/12733746/1745001. Notice that there's a `state` variable that contains the current state and it's being changed to the next state based on the current input, and tested to decide what input to accept, what to output and what the next state should be.

Comment: I am not qualified to explain the general rule of that link.
My extremely oversimplified understanding is : the print statement should be at the end.

Comment: That is not a general rule when using state machines.

Answer (score 2):

> a multiline which start with "{" somewhere of a line and end with "}"
> as the first character of a line

This sounds like task for [`getline`](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Plain-Getline.html) function, for simplicity sake let consider case where you want to get only 2 things made, above condition and *the first field of a line has the string "type" or "const" (all lowercase)* and you are working with following `file.txt`

```
this should become comment
type Boolean = 0 | 1
this too should become comment
function func(){
  if(true){
    console.log("This is not comment")
    return 123
  }
}
this also should comment
```

then

```
awk '$1~/type|const/{print;next}/{/{print;while(!/^}/){getline;print};next}{print "//",$0}' file.txt
```

gives output

```
// this should become comment
type Boolean = 0 | 1
// this too should become comment
function func(){
  if(true){
    console.log("This is not comment")
    return 123
  }
}
// this also should comment
```

Explanation: if 1st field contain `type` or `const`, then `print` line as-is and go to `next` line, if line contains `{` then `print` it as-is and use repeating `print`ing line until line starting with `}` character, when that is done go to `next` line. All lines which were not done yet will be prefixed by `//` and output field separator (default is space).

*(tested in GNU Awk 5.0.1)*

Comment: That would produce several lines of output that don't match the expected output. Also, if there was a missing `}` in the input it'd spin off into an infinite loop.